# How to add class to one element and remove from the rest in react

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-state-management

```
setSlideActive(event) {
  var getID = event.target.id
  console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getAttribute("id"))
  var iNum = getID.split("_")[1]
  iNum = --iNum
  this.setState({
    whichSlideActive: parseInt(iNum)
  })
}

generateSlides() {
  var count = 1
  var slideHTML = []
  var slideData = this.state.slideData
  var slideCount = Object.keys(slideData).length //count is 4
  for (var property1 in slideData) {
    slideHTML.push(
      <li key={count} id={"li_count_" + count}>
        <div className={"posRel hidO slideStyle slidenum_" + count} style={{
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + slideData[property1]["img-src"] + ')',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center center',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          }}>
            <span>
                {slideData[property1]["text-val"]}
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" id={"slide_" + count} onChange={(e) => this.setSlideActive} name="slide" checked={this.state.whichSlideActive === 0 ? "checked" : ""} />
        <label htmlFor={"slide_" + count}></label>
      </li>

    )
    count++
    var l = slideHTML
  }

  return slideHTML
}
```

How can I add a class to the div `slideStyle` respective to the input that was clicked?

```
.displayDiv {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

So if `slide_3` radio was clicked I want to only add the above class to the `slideStyle` div in the same `li` as the radio button and remove from other `li` divs

As a matter of fact I don't see the console.log() in the `setSlideActive` function when a radio is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You do not call `setSlideActive` at all. You need brackets. Make sure you call it like this:

```
onChange={() => this.setSlideActive()}
```

If you want to access the event that was emitted you can just pass it like this:

```
onChange={this.setSlideActive}
```

or

```
onChange={event => this.setSlideActive(event)}
```

Comment: @Si8 If it solved your problem please mark my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: It only answered part of my question unfortunately. I will wait for other replies, if there is, otherwise I will accept it as being answered. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Si8 What happens now that the `onChange` is fixed? I can help you further.